# Search a MySQL database in PhP

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am trying to search a `MySQL` database in `PhP` using `POST`, but I get the following errors:

`Notice: Undefined variable: ban1 in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/bans.php on line 266`

`Notice: Undefined variable: banner1 in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/bans.php on line 268`

`Notice: Undefined variable: bantl1 in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/bans.php on line 270`

`Notice: Undefined variable: banreason1 in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/bans.php on line 274`

`Notice: Undefined variable: ban2 in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/bans.php on line 276`

`Notice: Undefined variable: banner2 in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/bans.php on line 278`

`Notice: Undefined variable: bantl2 in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/bans.php on line 280`

`Notice: Undefined variable: banreason2 in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/bans.php on line 286`

**Here is my code:**

```
<h1>Punishments
 <div class='col-sm-3 col-md-3 pull-right' style='float:right'>
<div class='container'>
<div class='row'>
<div class='col-sm-3 col-xs-12 col-lg-3'>
  <form class='form-search' action='./bans.php' method='post'>
      <div class='input-group'>
          <input type='text' class='form-control' name='psch' placeholder='Search   Players'>
          <span class='input-group-btn'>
              <button type='submit' name='submitbtn' class='btn btn-search'><span   class='glyphicon glyphicon-search'></span></button>
          </span>
      </div>
  </form>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</h1>
<br>
<hr>";
$ban1 = "";

    require ("./connect.php");
if (isset($_POST['submitbtn'])) {
    $search = $_POST['psch'];
            $searched = mysql_real_escape_string($search);
    $result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM bans WHERE banned="$searched" ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0,1') or die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $ban1 = $row['banned'];
        $banner1 = $row['banner'];
        $bantl1 = $row['timeleft'];
        $banreason1 = $row['reason'];
        $banappeal1 = $row['appealed'];
        $banacceptor1 = $row['acceptor'];
        $bantime1 = $row['time'];
        }
    $result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM bans WHERE banned="$searched" ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1,1') or die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $ban2 = $row['banned'];
        }
    $result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM bans WHERE banned="$searched" ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 2,1') or die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $ban3 = $row['banned'];
        }
    $result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM bans WHERE banned="$searched" ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 3,1') or die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $ban4 = $row['banned'];
        }
    $result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM bans WHERE banned="$searched" ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 4,1') or die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $ban5 = $row['banned'];
        }
    echo "
        <div class='jumbotron'>
        <h1></h1>
            <p>
   <b>-----------------------------------------------</b>
   <br>
   <b>Banned:</b>$ban1
  <br>
    <b>Banner:</b>$banner1
<br>
<b>Time Left:</b>$bantl1
<br>
<b>Reason:</b>$banreason1
<br>
<b>-----------------------------------------------</b>
<br>
<b>Banned:</b>$ban2
<br>
<b>Banner:</b>$banner2
<br>
<b>Time Left:</b>$bantl2
<br>
<b>Reason:</b>$banreason2
<br>
<b>-----------------------------------------------</b>
</p>
            <p></p>
            </div>
        ";

    }
    else
```

I have tried declaring `ban1`, `banner1`, and all the other variables outside of the `while` statement, yet I still get those errors. Any ideas?

Comment: you don't need 4 queries, one would do

Comment: you should really use mysqli or PDO, the current version of PHP doesn't support old mysql

Comment: I'd like you post the mysql_error.It seems that the query occured to an error(I assumed that the query will return something).

Comment: @bixiaopeng how do I get the mysql_error, sorry I'm a beginner.

Comment: Well,I think I've made a mistake,you've already attach the error checker at the end of the query(die(...)).Would you like to make sure that the variable has been assigned the value you want?(such as attach a var_dump() after the value assignment.).

Answer (score 0):

You have to concatenate php variables with html like this

```
echo "
    <div class='jumbotron'>
    <h1></h1>
    <p>
    <b>-----------------------------------------------</b>
    <br>
    <b>Banned:</b>" . $ban1 .
    "<br>
    <b>Banner:</b>" . $banner1;
```

Comment: I tried that, but it doesn't work. Here is a pastebin of the entire file: http://pastebin.com/8yYLXnZc

Comment: Declare all variables outside the while loop and initialize it to some value and then try again.

Comment: I did that, but it didn't change them, they stayed the same as when I declared them before.

Comment: I don't get the errors anymore, but the valued are not what they are in the SQL database, they are what I set them to before.

Comment: I think it is an error before the mysql query because if I change the query line to:
`$result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM bans WHERE banned="'**Notch**'" ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0,1') or die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());`

instead of

`$result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM bans WHERE banned="'**$searched**'" ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0,1') or die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());`

**Notch** being a row in the database

Comment: Comment everything below the while loop, and print all your variables after that loop and exit after that. Try this thing and let me know

Comment: I still get `Notice: Undefined variable: ban1 in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/bans.php on line 203` for all of them, but different variables & line #s

Comment: have you declare all variables before while loop?

Comment: Try to print $result after "mysql_query" and exit from there. May be the query returns an error.

Comment: I get `Resource id #5`

Comment: Try to print mysql_fetch_assoc($result) instead of $result

Comment: It just says nothing.

Comment: Comment query and while loop and then try to run again

Comment: Now I get these errors
`
Notice: Undefined variable: result in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/bans.php on line 194

Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/bans.php on line 194`

Comment: instead of printing mysql_fetch_assoc(), print all variables

Comment: Comment query and while loop and after that print all your variables instead of printing mysql_fetch_assoc() and then try to run again

Comment: If I comment the query, then 
`   $ban1 = $row['banned'];
   $banner1 = $row['banner'];
   $bantl1 = $row['timeleft'];
   $banreason1 = $row['reason'];
   $banappeal1 = $row['appealed'];
   $banacceptor1 = $row['acceptor'];
   $bantime1 = $row['time'];
   }`
Can't attach to anything.

Comment: you have to comment everything after query[including query] and then print the variables. Also declare those variables before query

Comment: instead of echo ""$ban1 + $banner1 + $bantl1 + $banreason1 + $banappeal1 + $banacceptor1 + $bantime1 
do this

echo $ban1 . $banner1 . $bantl1 . $banreason1 . $banappeal1 . $banacceptor1 . $bantime1;

Comment: [`Here`](http://pastebin.com/rt0iwmLM) is everything that I tried . I think when I echo the ban stuff it has to be in the `if(isset)` statement, but it is still not setting them based on what is in the database.

Comment: uncomment all variables

Comment: then it just echos `abcdefg`

Comment: then there is something wrong with your query. now uncomment query and  while loop and keep every thing as it is like declare variables on top of query and print them after while loop. Try it and let me know

Comment: It still echos `abcdefg`

Comment: It means that your query returns empty result. Now comment all print statements and uncomment your other code. Now check whether that previous error of undefined variable comes or not. But make sure that you declare all variables on top of query.

Comment: if I don't print anything I don't get the errors, but If i replace the $search in the query with a value that I know is in the database, I can echo the stuff with no problem.

Comment: In such cases you should first check whether the query returns any records or not and then do your operations. Put such value in $search i.e. exists in your database and then run. It will give you proper result with valid values.

Comment: I'm kind of a beginner, how would I do that?

Comment: There are two options to do that 
1. You can either declare some default values to your variables in the begining and rest of the code as it is.

2.fire query, check whether query has return any records with mysql's "mysql_num_rows()" function. If it returns any record i.e. count of num rows != 0 then print all records with values else print nothing

Comment: Could I assign a specific variable to a certain column?

Comment: I didnt get your question. You are assigning certain column to variable in while loop right?

Comment: so that I can echo the column "Banned" and echo the column "Banner" in 2 different places.

Comment: But in your case the query doesnt returns anything. So If you want to print data always then set default values for all in the beginning itself i.e. before your query

Comment: But could I then change the value to the content of a cell?

Comment: I didnt get your question.Which cell?

Comment: Row:$search Column:Banned

Comment: Can you explain your problem in brief?

Comment: what you are trying to accomplish

Answer (score 0):

From PHP docs, you can see that

`E_NOTICE level error is issued in case of working with uninitialized variables, however not in the case of appending elements to the uninitialized array. isset() language construct can be used to detect if a variable has been already initialized.` You can find more info [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php)

So you have to initialize the variables inside your while loop before you use it to get rid of the notice.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that

```
if (isset($_POST['submitbtn'])) {
```

is true?  you might want to add an else statement to confirm.  or do you get the same error when you know it is false?